# Not able to read a specific JSON url using socket in Android

Tags: java, android, json, sockets

I want to read a Json URL using sockets and display it in a textbox.

When I use URLs other than my given URL, it shows the output file. But its not the same case with my URL. The content in the URL is very large (around 184,523 characters).

Here is the code that I am using:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  URLConnection feedUrl = null;
  String  json="";
  TextView txt;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myresponse);
            txt.setText("intialize");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            URLConnection feedUrl;
            try {
                feedUrl = new URL("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week").openConnection();
                InputStream is = feedUrl.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               String line = null;

               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();

             json=  sb.toString();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            txt.setText(json);
        }
    }.execute();
}
}
```

The URL is http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week. Please can someone tell why it is not running?

**One more question**: What should I do if I want to print only a specified object of the JSON file.
For example, if I want to print the entire 5th object instead of the whole file. What should I do in that case?

Comment: your json is invalid check this -->http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: @DIVA thanks, I have seen it, but that what is given in our assignment.
Can't we print the content in it just as any other file(as I am also doing it with httpclient and it is showing no error)

Comment: How do you want to get the 5th object if there are only 3 in that json?

Comment: without valid json u cannot parse it

Comment: @PedroOliveira,  sorry My bad, By object I want to say that , the entire object at index 5 of array "Features"
type,geometry , id acts as a whole thing and I want to print all these three

Comment: @DIVA I agree, but when I am doing it using HttpClient, it showing me the file as it is. What is the problem with the socket thing

Comment: as it is means? u will get raw data only na...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to format the result so you can get the actual JSON:

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("callback(") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(");")).matcher(json);

    while (matcher.find()) 
       json = matcher.group(1);
```

After you get the formated json you need to transform it into a JSONObject

```
   try{
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("features"); //get the features array
        JSONObject myObject= array.getJSONObject(5); //get the element 5
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now you have a jsonobject called myObject with the 5th feature.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :)
File is getting print when I am doing matcher.
But, when I am using the try clause,nothing is happenig
      String response="";
     JSONObject myObject= array.getJSONObject(5);
     response= myObject.toString();//response is another global string
      txt.settext(response);

I have done this, but now nothing is getting printed.

Comment: AFter that you do whatever you want with your jsonobject. I suppose you know how to work with JSONObject in android. Otherwise it's better to learn first